# Bokeh glyphs get cut off by edge of screen

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm plotting some circles of varying sizes (a bubble chart) in bokeh, but outliers towards the edge of the map are too big and the entire bubble isn't shown on the screen space. Is there a way to make sure a bokeh plot INITIALLY (when it first renders) contains everything, regardless of how big a bubble may be? There are work-arounds I could use, like plotting an invisible glyph at the edge of the bubbles, but I'd prefer a more direct solution, which I couldn't find anywhere in the documentation or on forums. Thanks!

Relevant code right now is as follows:

```
    p = figure(title=title, tools=TOOLS, plot_width=800, plot_height=700)
    p.xaxis.axis_label = x_label
    p.yaxis.axis_label = y_label
    p.circle(x=x_data,y=y_data, source=source,\
    size=bubble_radi,line_color=border_color,line_width=1,fill_alpha=.8)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you set the size of a glyph, it is defined in 'screen' units, which are not directly related to the data units. I think the easiest way to make sure that no part of the circles are cut off would be to define their radii in data units. This can be accomplished by setting the `radius` attribute, which by default is defined in data units, instead of the `size` attribute. (e.g. `p.circle(x=x_data, y=y_data, source=source, radius=bubble_radi)` and calculating the desired x-range and y_range based on the minimum and maximum data points plus/minus the circle radii.

Now, one tricky thing to consider is that the circle can only have one radius, which must be defined in either x-data units or y-data units. Assuming that the units are the same, you'll probably want to set the radius based on the y-data dimension, because your figure width is greater than the figure height. To do this you would use the `radius_dimension` attribute: `p.circle(x=x_data, y=y_data, source=source, radius=bubble_radi, radius_dimension='y')`

A full example is here:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Circle
import numpy as np
x_data, y_data = np.arange(0, 100, 10), 100-np.arange(0, 100, 10)

output_file("bubbles.html")

bubble_radi = 10.
border_color = 'red'

source = ColumnDataSource({'x_data': x_data, 'y_data': y_data})

x_range = (x_data.min() - bubble_radi, x_data.max() + bubble_radi)
y_range = (y_data.min() - bubble_radi, y_data.max() + bubble_radi)
p = figure(title='title', plot_width=800, plot_height=700, x_range=x_range,\
 y_range=y_range)
p.xaxis.axis_label = 'x_label'
p.yaxis.axis_label = 'y_label'
p.circle(x=x_data, y=y_data, source=source,\
radius=bubble_radi, radius_dimension='y',\
line_color=border_color,line_width=1,fill_alpha=.8)

show(p)
```

which returns this plot:
[image]